# Set whose average value is less than every element

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If you try to extend the notion of an (arithmetic) average to countably infinite sets, I think you'd have to have the average of the set $\{\frac{1}{n}$ | $n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ come out to be $0$, if you allowed it to be defined at all. This set would then have the property that its average is strictly less than each of its elements - a property no finite set has.

My question is: what's going on here? I know that's vague, but I bet there are some enlightening answers anyway.

Something like... "This is an example of a failure of the so-and-so property to hold. This can happen because you're working over $\mathbb{N}$, which is not such-and-such."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the "k"th partial sum of the reciprocals of the natural numbers, also knows as the "k"th harmonic number, we actually have an (almost) explicit formula for it.

$$ H_{k} = \ln(k) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2k} - \epsilon_{k} $$

Where $\gamma$ is a constant and $\epsilon_{k} \in [0, 1/8k^2]$. Because of this, we can compute the arithmetic mean of the first $k$ numbers in your set as $H_{k} / k$. However, we can actually express this explicitly.

$$H_{k}/k = \frac{\ln(k)}{k} + \frac{\gamma}{k} + \frac{1}{2k^2} - \frac{\epsilon_{k}}{k}$$.

Taking the limit as $k\rightarrow \infty$, we see that every one of these terms converges to $0$. What is happening here is that there are only 'finitely many' terms of magnitude greater than any number you can choose, and infinitely many of a smaller magnitude. When you take that 'infinite' average, the 'zero' terms dominate and pull the average to zero.

(If there are any mistakes here, feel free to yell at me! this is not my area of expertise).

EDIT: To better address your question -- if any sequence of numbers converges, your average will be computed with an 'infinite number' of that convergent value, and *should* pull the average toward that value. This average can be the infimum of the sequence as a whole, which will lead to the property that the arithmetic average is less than each member of the sequence. Though someone might have a fun counterexample to this claim I would love to see.

Comment: That's correct, this shows why the average value of this set is 0.

Answer (score 0):

If for $\{x_n\mid n\in \Bbb N\}$ we have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n}{n} \to 0,$$
then the average will be zero. Another example is $x_i=\frac{1}{i^3}$. For $x_i=\frac{1}{i}$ we obtain the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{O(\log(n))}{n}=0.
$$

Comment: Sure, that's another example of such a set. But my question is what is going on here, theoretically. No finite set can have this property, and come to think of it I don't think any continuous function over $\mathbb{R}$ can have this property either. So what is going on here?

Comment: Here's a way to ask it: Which sets of real numbers can have real-valued functions on them such that the average value of the function is less than each element of the set? No finite set can. $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ can. $\mathbb{R}$ cannot, I think. What's the general characterization?

Comment: Ah, this *can* happen on $\mathbb{R}$, e.g. the average of a Gaussian is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

A slight generalisation: If $\{a_n\}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence, then
$$
a_n \to a= \inf_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n \in [-\infty,\infty).
$$
In such case $a<a_n$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Meanwhile
$$
b_n=\frac{1}{n}(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)
$$
is also decreasing and has the same limit, i.e., $b_n\to a$. In fact, for every $m\in\mathbb N$,
$$
b_n<a_m, \quad \text{for sufficiently large $n$.}
$$